# Not complete match my Regular Expression with desired outcome in python3

Tags: python, regex

I have an expression as below: this expression can be repeated over the lines several times.

```
period={p1:{R:{M:'-1'}},p2:{R:{D:{start:'-28',end:'-1'}}
```

In python 3 I've written the following code:

```
RE_DAY_END = re.compile(r'(D:{start:\'-\d+\'\,end:\')+(?P<dend>\-[0-9]+)')
match_day= RE_DAY_END.findall(x)
print(match_day)
```

I can't undrestand what's happening that i am getting this output when i am expecting to get the other result:

```
  I am not interested:  [("D:{start:'-28',end:'", '-1')]

  I need this one:      [("D:{start:'-28',end:'-1')]
```

What kind of change should I do, in order to get the second result?

Comment: Revert all groups to non-capturing. Remove `dend` group. Or use `re.finditer` to access `.group(0)`. See https://ideone.com/dHAYUl

Comment: Read `pydoc3 re.findall` to understand what's happening.

Comment: Yes, that works for me thank you for your solution. As I see in this solution you also didn't remove dend group?

Comment: @MaryamPashmi I did not remove the groups since the solution is from the *Or use `re.finditer` to access `.group(0)`* opera.

Comment: are you going to write here your solution as I have to vote?

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach to extract single substring (`re.search()` function):

```
s = "period={p1:{R:{M:'-1'}},p2:{R:{D:{start:'-28',end:'-1'}}"
result = re.search(r'D:\{[^{}]+\}', s).group()
print(result)
```

The output:

```
D:{start:'-28',end:'-1'}
```

Comment: This is also interesting. the only point is that if u have several pattern in sentences is only find the first pattern for u and not the rest, maybe we can use findall instead of search. or using the solution of @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: I've used `re.search` according to your initial input and expected output. Of course, for multiple matches `re.findall` or `re.finditer` should be used

Comment: Also another point, is that in your expression i can't capture exactly start and end, if I have instead of these two word another, then will extract it for me as well. by the way can u start a little bit what is doing your expression?

Comment: @MaryamPashmi, you should elaborate your question and extend your desired result if you expect another result